# xarray.groupby() with ragged array

Tags: python-xarray

I have a semi-large dataset where for each trajectory [traj] there are a different number of observations [obs]. Because the number of observations varies from ~100—100000, they are combined into a ragged/jagged array as such. As you can see, some variables are defined per trajectory (`buoy_diameter`, `id`, and `count` which is the number of observations per trajectory) and others are defined per observations (`lon`, `lat`, `time`, `u`, `v`, `ids`).

```
# define data with variable attributes
data_vars = {
             'id': (['traj'], [11,22,33], {'long_name': 'trajectory id'}),
             'count': (['traj'], [2,3,4], {'long_name': 'number of observations per trajectory'}),
             'buoy_diameter': (['traj'], [0.3,0.4,0.5], {'units': 'm/s', 'long_name': 'drogue length'}),
             
             'u': (['obs'], [-1.1,-1.2,           # traj 1
                             -2.1,-2.2,-2.3,-3.1, # traj 2
                             -3.2,-3.3,-3.4],     # traj 3
                          {'units': 'm/s', 'long_name':'meridional velocity'}),
             'v': (['obs'], [1.2,1.3,          # traj 1
                             2.1,2.2,2.3,      # traj 2
                             3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4], # traj 3
                          {'units': 'm/s', 'long_name':'longitidunal velocity'}),
             'ids': (['obs'], [0,0,      # traj 1
                               1,1,1,    # traj 2
                               2,2,2,2], # traj 3
                          {'long_name': 'index of trajectory per observations'}),
             }

# define coordinates
coords = {  
            'lon': (['obs'], [10.,12.,         # traj 1
                              30.,34.,35.,      # traj 2
                              60.,61.,62.,63.]), # traj 3
            'lat': (['obs'], [0.,1.,           # traj 1
                              12.,13.,14.,      # traj 2
                              20.,22.,23.,24.]), # traj 3
            'time': (['obs'], [0.,1.,          # traj 1
                               0.,1.,2.,        # traj 2
                               0.,1.,2.,3.]),    # traj 3
         }

# create dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=data_vars,
                coords=coords, 
                attrs=attrs)
```

The trajectories have an associated `id` so I can use `groupby(id)`, but then each group contains all of the observations, so they can't be used to `map()` a function per trajectory.

```
gr = ds.groupby(id)
print(gr[11])
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (traj: 1, obs: 9)
Coordinates:
    lon            (obs) float64 10.0 12.0 30.0 34.0 35.0 60.0 61.0 62.0 63.0
    lat            (obs) float64 0.0 1.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 20.0 22.0 23.0 24.0
    time           (obs) float64 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
Dimensions without coordinates: traj, obs
Data variables:
    id             (traj) int64 11
    count          (traj) float64 2.0
    buoy_diameter  (traj) float64 0.3
    u              (obs) float64 -1.1 -1.2 -2.1 -2.2 -2.3 -3.1 -3.2 -3.3 -3.4
    v              (obs) float64 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4
    ids            (obs) int64 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

On the other hand, I also have an `ids` per observations that I can use to `groupby('ids')`, but as you can imagine now it contains all the trajectories.

```
gr = ds.groupby('ids')
print(traj_gr[0])
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (traj: 3, obs: 2)
Coordinates:
    lon            (obs) float64 10.0 12.0
    lat            (obs) float64 0.0 1.0
    time           (obs) float64 0.0 1.0
Dimensions without coordinates: traj, obs
Data variables:
    id             (traj) int64 11 22 33
    count          (traj) float64 2.0 3.0 4.0
    buoy_diameter  (traj) float64 0.3 0.4 0.5
    u              (obs) float64 -1.1 -1.2
    v              (obs) float64 1.2 1.3
    ids            (obs) int64 0 0
```

What I would like to obtain is a `DatasetGroupBy` with every group containing only one trajectory and the observation for this trajectory. I can obtain this manually using an extra `.sel()`:

```
for i, gr in ds.groupby('ids'):
    correct_gr = gr.sel(traj=[i])
    print(correct_gr)
```

with the first group as a reference containing 1 value for the variable per trajectory and 2 observations. (2nd group (traj: 1, obs: 3), 3rd gr (traj: 1, obs: 4)).

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (traj: 1, obs: 2)
Coordinates:
    lon            (obs) float64 10.0 12.0
    lat            (obs) float64 0.0 1.0
    time           (obs) float64 0.0 1.0
Dimensions without coordinates: traj, obs
Data variables:
    id             (traj) int64 11
    count          (traj) float64 2.0
    buoy_diameter  (traj) float64 0.3
    u              (obs) float64 -1.1 -1.2
    v              (obs) float64 1.2 1.3
    ids            (obs) int64 0 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added some details, hopefully it's clearer.